# For given $k$ and $N$ ($N>k$), what is the value of $B$ such that ${B\choose \frac{B}{2}}+{{N-B}\choose k-\frac{B}{2}}$ is minimized?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, combinations

For given $k$ and $N$ ($N>k$), what is the value of integer $B$ such that ${B\choose \frac{B}{2}}+{{N-B}\choose k-\frac{B}{2}}$ is minimized, where $\frac{B}{2}$ is a integer, $k-\frac{B}{2}>0$ and $N-B>0$.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?  Presumably we also have $N \gt k$.  Suppose $N$ is huge compared to $k$.  Any ideas there?

Comment: @RossMillikan Hi, Yes, $N$ is large compared to $k$. I have no clue even in this case, can you give some hints?

Comment: If $N \gg k$ the decrease in factors in $N \choose k$ doesn't matter and it is about $\frac 1{k!}N^k$  The second term will dominate over the first term unless $k-\frac B2$ is quite small.  Do you know any approximation or bound on ${B \choose \frac B2}?$

Comment: @Rossmillikan I don't know any bounds on it. Can you give me some reference? Thanks!